# How i can send the commands from keyboards using python. I am trying to automate mac app (GUI)

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a app using python. I need help to send keyboard commands through python. I am using powerBook G4.

Comment: Why aren't us using Mac OS Automator?  http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/

Answer (score 3):

You could call AppleScript from your python script with osascript tool:

```
import os
cmd = """
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "m" using {command down}' 
"""
# minimize active window
os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, python does not contain the ability to simulate keystrokes.  You can however use python to call a program which has the functionality that you need for OS X.  You could also write said program using Objective C most likely.

Or you could save yourself the pain and use Automator.  Perhaps if you posted more details about what you were automating, I could add something further.